# How to remove duplicate keys from Map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I am using Getx for state management in my cart app, When I add a product to cart and move to another page and come back and add that same product it is been added again. Due to this there are same products showing in cart. How do I solve this ?

this is my code :

```
  increment(Product product) {
    if (cart.containsKey(product)) {
      cart[product] += 1;
      
    } else {
      cart[product] = 1;
    }
     Get.snackbar("Product ", "Added",duration :const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  }
```

Comment: You should override `==` and `hashCode` in your `Product` class. See [implementing map keys](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys).

Comment: You have to use .toSet() method so it can be remove dups item from map